# VBScript: wait for Excel MsgBox, Click OK

Tags: excel, vbscript, automation, msgbox

I've written a VBScript that automates a load of processing of Excel workbooks.

For some of these workbooks, a MsgBox is triggered when they are opened. This message box is interrupting the automation.

Is there a way to listen for this MsgBox in a VBScript and "click" OK when it pops up?

Comment: VBScript or VBA? Message boxes are designed to halt and force the user to interact. If you just want a message you will probably want to create a userform (vba) to allow your script to continue. ignore me, i though you wanted the message box :D

Comment: There are options, but they tend to be complex, inelegant and/or  unreliable for any kind of production use.  If you let us know what messagebox you're trying to get around then we might be able to offer more useful advice.

Comment: @JamesSnell The messagebox is called from the VBA code within the sheet.

Comment: Well, so it's your code, if you don't want the msgbox then the most elegant solution is to get rid of it in the other sheets as getting around it is going to be a world of dirty hacks.  MsgBox should be banned IMHO.

Comment: @JamesSnell, I think the whole thing is a dirty hack, unfortunately I'm not in a position to do much about it. I can't get rid of the MsgBox, but I could temporarily disable it if the VBA somehow 'knew' that it was my script that opened the workbook, and not a user.

Comment: @Griffin - I hear you... been there, done that. :)  The quickest, dirtiest method might be to use a file as a marker.  If you create/copy a file into a specific name in the temp folder using vbscript, check for it in vba (showing the msgbox if the file doesn't exist) and delete it after in vbscript.   That's going to be about the cleanest option I can come up with off the top of my head.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this wrapper:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Workbooks.Open ([your code])
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

This will suppress any warnings on opening, e.g. compatibility issues, etc.

UPDATE:

In case MsgBox is generated from workbook code, try to use this:

```
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
```

In case Late Binding is used, this will work:

```
Application.AutomationSecurity = 3
```

Read more: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/886633

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had no luck with it

Comment: @Griffin could you please provide relevant piece of code? Or simply in your books there are macros that run on opening and trigger msgboxes?

Comment: good find, but unfortunately this only applies to Office for the Mac.

Comment: @Griffin I don't think so: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb220857%28v=office.12%29.aspx - link was just a sample. Anyway, it's a matter of seconds to try it out.

Comment: I tried before posting, I got `Variable is underfined: 'msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable', Code:800A01F4`

Comment: Could you please provide actual file to play with?

Comment: @Griffin: Replace `msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable` with `3` and it should work. You're using late binding, i.e. the interpreter has no real reference to the Excel library and therefore cannot translate `msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable`. If you go to the Excel VBE's Immediate window, type `? msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable`and you'll get the underlying integer!